# connecting oracle 8i with datasource method giving exception

Tags: oracle, datasource, oracle8i, ora-01034

I only have Oracle 8i installed in my system working fine. I can successfully connect using jdbc to it using driverManager but the problem occurs when I am using OracleDataSource to connect to it. It says Oracle not Available. I guess I am doing something wrong in providing the sid.

Part of my code -

```
       OracleDataSource ds = new OracleDataSource();
        ds.setDriverType("thin");
        ds.setServerName("localhost");
        ds.setPortNumber(1521);
        ds.setDatabaseName("ORCL0"); // sid
        ds.setUser("scott");
        ds.setPassword("tiger");
       Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
```

tnsnames.ora entry (part of it) -

```
 ORACLE =
   (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
     (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = guddus-comp)(PORT = 1521))
   )
     (CONNECT_DATA =
     (SERVICE_NAME = oracle)
  )
 )
```

listener.ora entry (part of it) -

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
(SID_LIST =
  (SID_DESC =
    (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
    (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oracle\ora92)
    (PROGRAM = extproc)
  )
  (SID_DESC =
    (GLOBAL_DBNAME = oracle)
    (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oracle\ora92)
    (SID_NAME = ORCL0)
  )
  (SID_DESC =
  (GLOBAL_DBNAME = dbabhi)
  (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oracle\ora92)
  (SID_NAME = DBABHI)
  )
)
```

---

In my code I'v tried oracle, orcl also in place of ORCL0 but anything other than ORCL0 gives Io exception: Connection refused whereas providing ORCL0 gives Exception - ORA-01034: ORACLE not available.... So I guess ORCL0 is correct but I anticipate some other problem.

Comment: Are you sure that you're using 8i, something that hasn't been supported in a decade?  The listener.ora you posted, assuming it comes from the server, is pointing to a directory that implies that you're using Oracle 9.2 which is still unsupported but at least somewhat recent.  If you are using 8i, exactly what version of 8i are you using?  And what version of the JDK and of the JDBC driver are you using?  Newer versions of Oracle client software drops support for older versions of Oracle eventually.

Comment: Justin, I am using Oracle 8i Release 8.1.5 (from Readme). I too am not sure whether it will connect to 8i and thats d reason for my question. I am using Eclipse Indigo, Java SE 1.6, and ojdbc14-1.jar. Shall it support?

Comment: What version of the JDBC driver are you using?  Are you using the 11.2.0.3 JDBC driver, the 10.2.0.5 JDBC driver, etc.?  I'm not aware of any version of the JDBC driver where ojdbc14.jar is compatible with a 1.6 JVM.  The 1.6 JVM drivers are all, to the best of my knowledge, called ojdbc6.jar.  So it looks like you have a mismatch between the version of the JVM you're using and the version of the JDBC driver that you're using before we even start looking at the version of Oracle.

Comment: Driver version is 9.0.2.0.0 in ojdbc14.jar I suppose it does not support 1.6 JVM. I uninstalled oracle 8i as there was no point keeping it.. Installing Oracle 11g XE... Will try the same thing and update thereafter in this post. Great Thanks Justin for the help

Comment: Hi Justin, Iv installed Oracle 11g now and rest everything is pretty much unchanged. As I speculated odbc14.jar (driver 9.0.2.0.0) supports Java 1.6 and so everything is working fine. The problem was probably Oracle 8i not supporting the newer jdbc driver. (or least may b 8i din support Java 1.6)